# Javascript Compare 2 array of object based on key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have 2 arrays of objects below. I want to compare both and check the matched random_code and get the score 
based on the matched random code. I have provided the sample result below. Thanks

## me.records.data1(array of objects)

```
[
        {
            id: 345,
            user: 223,
            random_code: "50-3910111611011",
            created_at: "2019-03-01",
            is_verified: false,
            …
        }   1:{
        id: 346,
            user:223,
                random_code:"50-101966854102",
                    created_at:"2019-03-01",
                        is_verified:false,
      …
   }
]
```

me.records.data2(array of objects)

```
[  
   {  
      id:161,
      questionaire_content:80,
      questionaire_content_choice:272,
      created_at:"2019-03-01",
      random_code:"50-3910111611011",
      score:"0",
      …
   }   1:{  
      id:162,
      questionaire_content:79,
      questionaire_content_choice:270,
      created_at:"2019-03-01",
      random_code:"50-101966854102",
      score:"1",
      …
   }
]
```

## result should be like this based on the data above.

```
]{  
id:345,
user:223,
random_code:"50-3910111611011",
created_at:"2019-03-01",
score:0,
is_verified:false,
…
}{  
id:346,
user:223,
random_code:"50-101966854102",
created_at:"2019-03-01",
score:1,
is_verified:false,
…
}
```

]

Comment: Please share some code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. Iterate over the source array.
2. For each item in the source array, get the “random_code” key for the object, and store the value in a temporary variable.
3. From the scores array, find an object whose “random_code” matches the one stored in the temporary variable, if found, return the “score” key’s value.

```js
const source = [
  {
    id: 345,
    user: 223,
    random_code: "50-3910111611011",
    created_at: "2019-03-01",
    is_verified: false,
  }, {
    id: 346,
    user:223,
    random_code:"50-101966854102",
    created_at:"2019-03-01",
    is_verified:false,
  }
];

const scores = [
  {  
      id:161,
      questionaire_content:80,
      questionaire_content_choice:272,
      created_at:"2019-03-01",
      random_code:"50-3910111611011",
      score:"0",
   }, {  
      id:162,
      questionaire_content:79,
      questionaire_content_choice:270,
      created_at:"2019-03-01",
      random_code:"50-101966854102",
      score:"1",
   }
];

// function to get the value of score key from scores array for matching random code.
const getScoreForRandomCode = (randomCode) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < scores.length; index++) {
    const tempScore = scores[index];
    if (tempScore.random_code === randomCode) {
      return tempScore.score;
    }
  }
}

const result = source.map ((item) => {
  const randomCode = item.random_code;
  const score = getScoreForRandomCode (randomCode);
  return {
    ...item,
    score: score || 'NA'
  };
});

console.log (result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach to loop through the me.records.data1, and match the random_code within me.records.data2. When the random_code matched, will assign the data2.score to me.records.data1.

```
me.records.data1.forEach(function(obj){  
    var bscore = ""; 
    data2 = me.records.data2.find(function(i) { if(i.random_code === obj.random_code) return i.score; });
    if(bscore!="") obj.score = data2.score;
});
```

Comment: i did try this but it only return a single object. It should return array of objects me.records.data1 with key score and value.

Comment: each score from me.records.data2 should be added on each in me.records.data1

Comment: Do you mean the score in me.records.data2 has the duplicated random_code and need to sum up the duplicated random_code's score?

Comment: the return of the logic should be

Comment: 0: {id: 345, user: 223, random_code: "50-3910111611011", created_at: "2019-03-01", score:  0, is_verified: false, …}
1: {id: 346, user: 223, random_code: "50-101966854102", created_at: "2019-03-01", score: 1 ,  is_verified: false, …}

Comment: please look at array of objects2 (me.records.data2) scores and random code.

Comment: I have updated the question bro. please kindly look at it